# tmux on Windows Linux Subsystem yields spurious characters

Tags: windows-10, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I start up tmux on Windows, I get a bunch of weird characters that I have to delete:

```
^[[?1;0ceddie@OPTIMUS ~ $ 1;0c
```

Even if I comment out my .bashrc and .tmux.conf, I still get this.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been experiencing this as well and hadn't bothered chasing it down until just now. I quickly discovered [this issue in the BashOnWindows project](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1638), which at least for me resolved the issue. I do have a `set -s escape-time 0` line in my .tmux.conf, and commenting it out (or renaming my .tmux.conf so it wouldn't be loaded) did the trick.